# When installing ROS No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'

Tags: macos, installation, pip, homebrew, ros

I am following the instructions for intsalling `ROS` on OSX. When I enter the command `pip --version` I get the following error. Here's [the manual](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) I am following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==6.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 552, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2672, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2345, in load
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2351, in resolve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 38, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.cachecontrol import CacheControlAdapter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 92, in load_module
    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'
```

You know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following to get it work:

1. `brew install openssl`
2. `brew unlink python`
3. `brew install python`
4. `sudo easy_install pip`